# Problemas de acentuação em sql

Tags: jsp

Estou com problemas de acentuação no cadastro. Se eu cadastrar nomes com acento, eles saem confusos, eu não sei se é algum problema de sql. Já mudei o utf8 para isso mas o texto do site fica confuso.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cadastro_costumização.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
}
h1{
    color:#00F;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:24px;

}
p{
    color:#003
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:22px;

}
table{
    background-color: #69F;
}
-->
</style></head>

<body>

<p align="center">Manunten&ccedil;&atilde;o do Bairro</p>
<p align="center"><img src="img/loja.png" width="290" height="158" /></p>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('imprime_usuario.jsp')">impress&atilde;o na tela cheia</a>
<div align="center"></br> <p>Cadastre e Impresse
aqui</p>
  <a href="bairro_cadastro.jsp"><img src="img/cadstrar.png" width="82" height="83" /></a><a href="imprime_usuario.jsp"><img src="img/indice.jpg" width="82" height="83" /></a>
<h1><strong>Ordena&ccedil;&atilde;o: <a href="bairro.jsp?ordenacao=crescente">Crescente</a>- <a href="bairro.jsp?ordenacao=alfabetica">Alfab&eacute;tica</a></strong></h1></div>
<div align="center" > 
  <table width="777" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="150"><div align="center"><p>C&oacute;digo</p></div></td>
      <td width="251"><div align="center">
        <p>Nome do bairro</p></div></td>

      <td width="254"><div align="center"><p>Alterar</p></div></td>
      <td width="104"><div align="center"><p>Excluir</p></div></td>
    </tr>

     <% 

try
{
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    //out.println("Conceguiu carregar o drive<br>");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/js","postgres","1974");
    //out.println("Conexão com sucesso");

    Statement st = con.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    //out.println("passou pelo Statement ");
    if(request.getParameter("acao")!= null)
    {
    st.executeUpdate("delete from bairro where bai_codigo="+request.getParameter("codigo"));
    }
    ResultSet rs = null;

    if(request.getParameter("ordenacao")== null)
    {
         rs = st.executeQuery("select * from bairro order by bai_nome ");
    }

    else if(request.getParameter("ordenacao").equals("crescente"))
    {
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from bairro ");  
    }

    else if(request.getParameter("ordenacao").equals("alfabetica"))
    {
    rs = st.executeQuery( "select * from bairro order by bai_nome");    
    }

    while(rs.next())
    { %>

    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><%=rs.getString("bai_codigo")  %></div>
      </td>
      <td><div align="center"> <%=rs.getString("bai_nome")  %></div></td>

      <td><div align="center">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <a href="bairro_altera.jsp?codigo=<%=rs.getString ("bai_codigo")%>&amp;bairro=<%=rs.getString("bai_nome")%>"><img src="img/POWER - SWITCH USER.png" width="30" height="30" /></a>
        </form>
      </div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><a href="bairro.jsp?acao=excluir&amp;codigo=<%=rs.getString("bai_codigo")%>"><img src="img/Lixeiras_1545_Poubelle_v3.png" width="30" height="30" /></a></div></td>
    </tr>

  <%   }
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException erroClass)
{
    out.println("Driver não localizado,erro="+ erroClass); 
    }
catch(SQLException erroSQL)
{
out.println("Erro de conexão com o Banco de dados,erro="+ erroSQL); 
}

%>

  </table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tente: <%=out.println(rs.getString("bai_codigo")) %> ; <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> e <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

Comment: adiciona isso <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='UTF-8'>

Comment: Não consegui, da erro

Answer (score 0):

Esclarece uma duvida. Você esta salvando os dados e no banco de dados foi salvo com o carácter acentuado quebrado? Ou quando carrega a informação do banco para o HTML, ele esta quebrado? Se você quer salvar dados com acentuação, recomendo criar a conexão da seguinte forma:

```
jdbc:postgresql://" + hostName + "/" + dataBase + "?charSet=LATIN1"
```

Lembrando que o encode UTF-8 não possui acentuação

Comment: Acredito que você não tenha lido minha resposta e também não entendeu o problema dele. Ele esta com problema de acentuação, criando uma conexão com o banco de dados sem especificar o charset utilizado pelo banco. Ele criando a conexão utilizando "jdbc:postgresql://hostName+dataBase + ?charSet=LATIN1" resolve o problema dele.

Answer (score 0):

Tentei desta maneira
jdbc:postgresql://" + hostName + "/" + dataBase + "?charSet=LATIN1"
que seria desta forma 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:postgresql://" + localhost/js + "/" + dataBase + "?ENCODING=LATIN1");
Deu erro